# Travelling to Schengen countries from UK with multi entry UK visa

Tags: schengen, business-travel, schengen-visas, new-delhi, vfs-global

I am an Indian National holding an Indian passport. Currently, I have obtained a multi-entry UK Business Visitor Visa from New Delhi, India. During my stay in Edinburgh, UK, I plan to travel to the neighbouring Schengen countries (France and Netherlands) and I am applying for Schengen Tourist visa for the same. However, my company will book the tickets to and from India and UK near the date of travel. Would I need those tickets to be shown in Schengen visa application? My Schengen travel will be from London-Paris-Amsterdam and finally Edinburgh, UK. Will I need to submit the tickets as well in the Schengen application?
Also, I have mentioned my business visit details in cover letter, but do I need to show tickets for that as well i.e. for travel within UK?

Comment: I might be wrong but you can't go to other Schengen areas using the multiple entry business visitor visa?

Comment: The UK is not part of Schengen. The multi-entry business visitor is valid only for the UK.

Comment: Hi Newton and Tom. Of course I'm aware of the same. That's the reason I'm applying for Schengen visa separately. What I was asking was that my Schengen tourist trip is from London-Paris-Amsterdam-Edinburgh, but I'm flying in and out of Edinburgh, so would it be compulsory to attach those tickets as well?

Answer (score 1):

You should document everything you can, so ask your company if they could book the tickets a bit earlier and then E-mail or fax copies to you.

If they insist on doing it last-minute, then ask them to at least E-Mail/fax copies of whatever documentation *currently available* pertaining to the purpose of your trip to France and the Netherlands. Also ask them to write a letter of invitation stating your purpose and duration of stay in the Schengen Area, and that the tickets have yet to be booked, hence the absence of them amongst the documentation sent with the application.

Comment: I have obtained an NOC and a visa leave letter from my office. Will attach the itinerary too. Thanks a ton! :)